# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/ carthage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, carthage

I'm having this crash when running on a simulator where the os cannot find the carthage frameworks

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/
```

I see [Alamodfire issue](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/101) but, closed.

my xcode settings

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do app running?

source code: [konojunya/github-repository-search](https://github.com/konojunya/github-repository-search)